# How do I find net resistance of the given circuit?

Tags: resistance

I want to find the net resistance of a given circuit,

[image: given circuit]

But, I cannot break it down into just series and parallel. When I try to I get,

[image: simplified circuit]

And I don't understand how to go about finding net resistance after this since there is no clear series and parallel.

Comment: For one thing your "breakdown" schematic is incorrect.  Note that you have shorted R10 and R11 and they don't factor into your equivalent resistance at all now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent resistance with complicated net](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83151/equivalent-resistance-with-complicated-net)  not the best answer yet most points, but if you search , you will find better ones. I suggest you learn this searching skill with key words before anything else, which I leave for you to do as homework.

Comment: By "net resistance" I am assuming you mean, "what resistance does the voltage source see when connected to this resistor network?"

Comment: E.g. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/mesh-current-method/

Comment: Once you do this a bunch, you can visualize the  parallel R's and short cct's in your reduction ;) immediately....  R1//R3 R4//R6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, draw it correctly.  Aside from R2, all your resistors are going to ground.  R1 and R3 are in parallel, as are R5 and R6.

If you're looking for total resistance across the battery, it's not particularly important where ground is in the circuit.

Taking ground out, you have 3 series resistance elements:  R2, R1||R3, and R5||R6.  You should be able to take it from there.